# Starlet '98 wheel key

Tags: toyota, car, wheels, old-cars, starlet

The wheels on my Starlet '98 (European XLi version) have a cap over the nuts. The cap is locked in place with a lock which appears to need a square key with a hole in the middle.

[image: Wheel cap lock]

What is such a lock called and what kind of key do I need for it? At the moment I open them with a flat screwdriver lacking a better idea. One of the locks is in [poor shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJg4B.jpg) already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be looking for a bit which is something like in the following diagram, but I wouldn't know what size you'd need:

[image]

Comment: Square drive, apparently that's the term I was looking for. Turns out they even have screwdrivers like this, Roberson screwdrivers, although those don't usually have a hole in the middle. This answer got me at least on the right track, I'll update once I know the exact tool for the job.

Comment: In the end I got a square piece of brass-ish metal, cut it to fit (left about 9mm each side) and drilled a 5.5mm hole in the middle. It's not pretty, but it does the job better than a flat screwdriver.

Comment: @Mast - Whatever works :o) Glad you got it done.